# Why does the Wolff algorithm slow down in a 4-body Ising model?

Tags: ising-model, monte-carlo, solid-state-physics, k-local-hamiltonians

In the [paper](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.95.041101) that introduced "Self-learning MC" (an ML-inspired MC technique, as I understand) the authors consider a many-body Ising model as an example to show the efficiency of their algorithm. The model looks like this:
\begin{equation}
H= -J \sum_{\langle i,j\rangle} S_i S_j - K \sum_{ijkl\in p}S_iS_jS_k S_l \tag{1} ,
\end{equation}
where the second term runs for all plaquettes $p$ on the square lattice.

In the paper, I found an explanation that says *"For $K=0$,
this model reduces to the standard Ising model which can
be simulated efficiently by the Wolff method. However, for
$K\neq0$, no simple and efficient global update method is known."*
The Wolff algorithm **can** be applied to this model, and they indeed compare the "naive Wolff algorithm" with the new self-learning MC. It seems that while the Wolff algorithm does speed up MC compared to local updates, it still has a very similar asymptotic suffering in relaxation (Fig 3 in the paper).

My question is this:
Is there an intuitive way to understand ***why*** this slowing down happens in the Wolff algorithm? To me, it seems like it might work just fine as in the 2-body Ising model, because it's not that different (at least in terms of implementation).

Comment: Discussion about this question, including the answer to the above comment, is taking place in [this chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57423533#57423533).